# React Native - Exception thrown while executing UI block - unrecognized selector?

Tags: javascript, react-native, animation, components, expo

I'm working with React Native in expo and trying to animate a change in scale. I've separated out https://github.com/tongyy/react-native-draggable#readme into its own folder and am modifying the source code (Draggable.tsx).

Markup returns an Animated.View here-

```
return (
    <Animated.View pointerEvents="box-none" style={positionCss}>
      {debug && getDebugView()}
      <Animated.View
        pointerEvents="box-none"
        {...animatedViewProps}
        {...panResponder.panHandlers}
        style={pan.current.getLayout()}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          {...touchableOpacityProps}
          onLayout={handleOnLayout}
          style={dragItemCss}
          disabled={disabled}
          onPress={onShortPressRelease}
          onLongPress={onLongPress}
          onPressIn={onPressIn}
          onPressOut={handlePressOut}>
          {touchableContent}
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Animated.View>
    </Animated.View>
  );
```

with this return in dragItemCss:

```
 return {
          ...style,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          width: renderSize,
          height: renderSize,
          transform: [{scaleX: 2}, {scaleY: 2}], //HERE
          shadowColor: 'black',
          shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 0.5 * 20 },
          shadowOpacity: 0.1,
          shadowRadius: 0.8 * 20,
        };
      }, [children, isCircle, renderColor, renderSize, x, y, z]);
```

I should be able to set styles here. I need to modify transform scale values over time, so I first tried the above, and the button scaled with no errors.

When I plug in `scale` to the transform style, however, I get an error

```
const scale = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(1));
```

> Exception thrown while executing UI block - [NSDictionaryM floatValue]
> unrecognized selector

What is happening here? How can I animate a change in this component's scale?